# Regex to restrict input into latitude (in decimal degrees) textbox

Tags: c#, regex

I have a WPF application with a textbox where my user will enter a latitude value in decimal degrees (with *up to* 7 digits of precision).  Valid latitudes range from -90.0000000 to 90.0000000, of course.  I'm trying to create a regex to restrict input via the PreviewTextInput event for the textbox similar to this:

```
    private void latitudeTextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !ValidateDecimalString(e.Text);
    }

    public static bool ValidateDecimalString(string decimalString)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
        return !regex.IsMatch(decimalString);
    }
```

My current regex allows only numbers to be entered but there are some other limitations that I need to enforce as well like:

- the latitude could be negative so I need to allow for the minus sign ("-") but only if it appears as the first character
- the latitude can only contain a single decimal point (".")

Examples of valid latitude values:

- 90
- 90.0
- -90.0000000

Can I achieve these additional restrictions just by modifying my regex?  If so, how?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
public static bool ValidateDecimalString(string decimalString)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(-)?([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+)?$");
    return regex.IsMatch(decimalString);
}
```

for validate range better use converted value like

```
public static bool ValidateLatitudeString(string decimalString)
{
    if(ValidateDecimalString(decimalString)){
        double lat = 0;
        return double.TryParse(decimalString, out lat) && lat<=90.0 && lat>=-90;
    }
    return false;
}
```

so possibly better will be without regex like

```
public static bool ValidateLatitudeString(string decimalString)
{
    double lat = 0;
    return double.TryParse(decimalString, out lat) && lat<=90.0 && lat>=-90;
}
```

Comment: Nice clean answer. If you intend to use this function a lot, you may want to put it in an extension class, `DecimalStringExtender` or something, and change the parameter to `this string decimalString`. You can also get some performance gains by storing the `Regex` as a static member variable (`static readonly Regex DecimalRegex = ...`). Lastly, consider the `RegexOptions.Compiled` for additional performance gains.

Comment: what about -99999999Z999999 with your regex?

Comment: *Valid latitudes range from -90.0000000 to 90.0000000* => `ValidateDecimalString("999");` ????

Comment: @L.B - true :-) regex should not test range, but test format, for testing range better after regex use converting and compare

Comment: Your logic suggests `+89.` and `-.0` are not between decimal -90. and 90. These should pass the form test, otherwise, the form should be the only test.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public static bool ValidateDecimalString(string decimalString)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^-?([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)([.][0-9]*)?$");
    return regex.IsMatch(decimalString);
}
```

This will allow an optional leading hyphen-minus, followed by a number from 0 to 90 inclusive (but not 999 or 01), followed by optionally a decimal component. It will allow `90.1` though; to forbid this use:

```
public static bool ValidateDecimalString(string decimalString)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("^-?(([0-9]|[1-8][0-9])([.][0-9]*)?|90([.]0*))$");
    return regex.IsMatch(decimalString);
}
```

This will allow `90.0` but not `90.1`.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of options for this. One way -

```
 #  @"^-?(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:\.[0-9]{1,7})?|90(?:\.0{1,7})?)$"

 ^ 
 -?
 (?:
      (?:
           [0-9] 
        |  [1-8] [0-9] 
      )
      (?: \. [0-9]{1,7} )?
   |  
      90  
      (?: \. 0{1,7} )?
 )
 $
```

Matching *giant* edge case

```
 #  @"^-?(?:(?:[0-9]|[1-8](?:[0-9]|$))(?:\.(?:[0-9]{1,7}|$))?|9(?:0|$)(?:\.(?:0{1,7}|$))?)?$"

 ^ 
 -?
 (?:
      (?:
           [0-9]  
        |  [1-8] (?: [0-9] | $ )
      )
      (?:
           \. (?: [0-9]{1,7} | $ )
      )?
   |  
      9 (?: 0 | $ )
      (?:
           \. (?: 0{1,7} | $ )
      )?
 )?
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

While your question is how do I validate latitude with regex it seems like a better approach would be to use something like Decimal.TryParse.

```
 public static bool ValidateLatitudeString(string decimalString)
    {
        decimal validLatitude;
        if (decimal.TryParse(decimalString, out validLatitude))
        {
            if (validLatitude >= -90.0M && validLatitude <= 90.0M)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I have an existing validation rule like this that checks the range of the number once it's been entered.  What I'm trying to accomplish with the regex is to simply restrict input into textbox (hence the use of the PreviewTextInput event).

Comment: @user685869 Hm in this case, why don't you just validate with `"^-?[0-9]+([.][0-9]*)?$"`? Although, see my answer for something that gets the numbers mostly or fully checked correctly, it's not that different.

Comment: Fair enough. If you are already validating that way on the back end maybe just have a regex that allows numbers . and -.  If they goof it up with something like 99.9 then use the back end validation to catch it.  Not that you couldn't write some long regex that would work in all edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

another way `^-?[0-8]?\d(?:\.\d*)?|-?90(?:\.0+)?$` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eA8uR6)

Answer (score 0):

another way (example with double) - not regex solution but works

```
        bool IsDigitsOnlyLatitudaLongituda(string str, int deg)
        {
    // deg with value 0 is latitude, deg with value 1 is longitude
            bool provjera = true;
            int brojactocki = 0;
            if (str.Length > 0)
            {
                if (str[0] == '.')
                {
                    provjera = false;
                }
                if (str[str.Length - 1] == '.')
                {
                    provjera = false;
                }
            }
            var brojac = 0;
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                brojac = brojac + 1;
                if (brojac != 1)
                {
                    if (c == '-')
                    {
                        provjera = false;
                    }
                }
                if (c == '.')
                {
                    brojactocki = brojactocki + 1;
                }
            }
            if (brojactocki > 1)
            {
                provjera = false;
            }
            foreach (char c in str)
            {
                if ((c < '0' || c > '9') && (c != '.') && (c != '-'))
                {
                    provjera = false;
                }
            }
            double dblString;
            if (deg == 0)
            {
                if (provjera == true)
                {
                    dblString = Convert.ToDouble(str.Replace(".", ","));
                    if (dblString >= 90 || dblString <= -90)
                    {
                        provjera = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (deg == 1)
            {
                if (provjera == true)
                {
                    dblString = Convert.ToDouble(str.Replace(".", ","));
                    if (dblString >= 180 || dblString <= -180)
                    {
                        provjera = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return provjera;
        }
```